# Create Twig filter to display results conditional on being defined

Tags: php, twig

I wish to display text based on a given value per the following table:

- If `row.someProp` is `0` or `false`, display "No"
- If `row.someProp` is `1` or `true`, display "Yes"
- If `row.someProp` is not defined, display "N/A"

My attempt to do so is as follows, however, it results in the following error: `Key "someProp" for array with keys id, name, unit, slope, intercept, type, typeName does not exist.`

```
$filter = new \Twig_SimpleFilter('yesNoNa', function ($v) {
    return isset($v)?($v?'Yes':'No'):'N/A';
});

row.somePro|
```

How is this best accomplished?

Comment: apparently you don't, because that is not ternary, `??` is null coalesce,  ternary is `(condition) ? true : false`  In plain PHP `echo empty(row.someProp) "No" : "Yes";`  `N/A` you have to check `isset` for

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  Agree.  I am currently doing `{{ row.trend|default ? (row.trend?'Yes':'No'):'N/A' }}` which is a little clunky but will work.

Comment: I don't use twig, However i have looked at the source code for it a while ago.  It's a good template system.  Just remember templates are for display not business logic.  If this is a query, you can do modification in the SQL too.  Personally it's something I would do before putting it in the template

Comment: Can you share more context? What have you tried so far? What defines the "best way" from your POV?

Comment: @DarkBee I just assumed that `row.trend|default` returns true if defined.  Evidently not and I better read the docs.

Comment: @NicoHaase  I tried the snippet in the comments.  From my POV, concise is important so the code is not overly cluttered.

Comment: As a long-term user of SO, you should know to put all relevant information in the question itself, not to the comment section.

Comment: @DarkBee  Need to or want to create a custom filter?  PS.  I like your twigfiddle link.  Never knew it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with creating a "simple" filter in `twig` is that it does'nt  account for undefined variables/properties. To solve this you would need to create your own `node class` with the same behavior as the `default` filter

Step 1. Register the filter/function with a node class

```
$filter = new \Twig_SimpleFilter('yesNoNa', function ($v) {
    return isset($v)?($v?'Yes':'No'):'N/A';
}, [ 'node_class' => \MyProject\Base\Twig\Expression\Filter\YesNoNa::class);
```

Step 2. Create the node class

```
namespace MyProject\Base\Twig\Expression\Filter;

class YesNoNa extends \Twig_Node_Expression_Filter_Default {
    public function __construct(\Twig_NodeInterface $node, \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant $filterName, \Twig_NodeInterface $arguments, $lineno, $tag = null)
    {
        $yesNoNa = new \Twig_Node_Expression_Filter($node, new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant('yesNoNa', $node->getLine()), $arguments, $node->getLine());

        if ('yesNoNa' === $filterName->getAttribute('value') && ($node instanceof \Twig_Node_Expression_Name || $node instanceof \Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr)) {
            $test = new \Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Defined(clone $node, 'defined', new \Twig_Node(), $node->getLine());
            $false = count($arguments) ? $arguments->getNode(0) : new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant('N/A', $node->getLine());

            $node = new \Twig_Node_Expression_Conditional($test, $yesNoNa, $false, $node->getLine());
        } else {
            $node = $yesNoNa;
        }

        parent::__construct($node, $filterName, $arguments, $lineno, $tag);
    }
}
```

---

To find out about this class I've just dug into the source to find out how the default filter was defined inside the core.

It seems this line, `$false = count($arguments) ? $arguments->getNode(0) : new \Twig_Node_Expression_Constant('N/A', $node->getLine());` will defin the 'default' output when a variable isn't defined. (Hence the N/A in there)

---

Using the filter now in my sandbox produces this output:

```
{% set foo = false %}
{% set bar = true %}
{% set foobar = null %}
{% set arr = { 10: 'foobar', 1: 'foo', 5 : 'bar', 'foo': 42, } %}

Foo: {{ foo | yesNoNa }}                {# No #}
Bar: {{ bar | yesNoNa }}                {# Yes #}
Undefined: {{ undefined | yesNoNa }}    {# N/A #}
Foobar: {{ foobar | yesNoNa }}          {# N/A #}
foo.bar.foo {{foo.bar.foo | yesNoNa }}  {# N/A #}
arr.foo {{ arr.foo | yesNoNa }}         {# Yes #}
```

---

*This was tested in `twig 1.X` - It could be that this solution requires the correct namespaces for all used `twig` classes instead of the root ones in `twig 2.x`*